# Dealing with a completely changed question with answers to both

Tags: discussion, questions, editing, answers

[This question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33416) has been changed nearly 100% from its original form, but now has valid answers from before and after the change.  In [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64459/rolling-back-a-completely-changed-question) on meta.se they talk about rolling the question back when there's only answers to the original form, but searches there and here didn't reveal any cases where the question in both forms had valid answers.  I put some time and thought into writing my original answer and after a few rounds of discussion, the OQ went and essentially replaced the original question.  I'd hate to see my work amount to naught as the answer is clearly off axis for the new question.  But, the same goes for the authors of the later two answers.  Is there a way to get the original and reworded question split?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, these things happen. If you think the original question and your answer really are worth preserving, you can consider posting the question and answering it yourself. I don't think there's any other solution, there's no way to split the original question as if it was posted by the original poster.